# Webpack and clientside module loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, webpack

I'm comparing how RequireJS and Webpack works, and there's something I still don't get:

RequireJS is loaded in the browser through a `<script>` tag, e.g.:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

In its simplest implementation, it uses the data-main attribute to set its base path and loads asynchronously every js in it

Webpack works in Nodejs environment. You install it via `npm install` cmd. Then you set the entry point and other stuffs in the webpack.config file

```
 module.exports = {
     entry: './src/app.js',
     output: {
         path: './bin',
         filename: 'app.bundle.js'
     }
 };
```

When you run `webpack` cmd your entry point is read and its dependencies are loaded and bundled together in the output file (in this case, app.bundle.js).

This two behaviors seems to me really differents (RequireJS run and loads in browser, Webpack in Node), and I don't understand why this two module system are mentioned as interchangeable.

**In particular it seems to me that webpack doesn't do anything special, it only concatenates a bunch of js together.** What am I missing?